# Joining tables on IDs with different variable sizes

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Can a JOIN use an index when there is a variable range mismatch between joined tables e.g, an id is varchar(10) in one table, varchar(11) in the other table where it is Foreign key? I know that it does not work if the types are different, but not sure if the same is the case with different ranges.

Also, the range on INT types e.g, INT(10) or INT(11) do not really affect anything except formatting if you are using ZEROFILL. The storage capacity for both INTs above is the same. However, like in my first question, can a JOIN use an index when there is a range mismatch on INT types between joined tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the index should work where the size of the varchar fields are different.

In this case you shouldn't have any issues with the foreign keys since the field in the child table has a larger size.  If it was the other way around, you could get errors if the foreign key value was larger than the varchar field allowed in the child table.